# Using App.Current.Terminate() method in Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

As windows phone 8 provides us with this method for programmatically terminate an app, will there be any issue while app submission if we use this in app for terminating a page while there is no backentry in the navigation history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There won't be any issue in certification when using this call, but make sure you have saved all data in your app when calling this, because this call effectively kills your app immediately - ApplicationClosing even handler won't be raised after it!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you call Application.Terminate when navigating back with an empty back stack? Just let the app close itself. Seems a bit pointless to me to overuse Application.Terminate().

Comment: it's something like logout...on clicking logout i want to close the app

Answer (score 0):

I can't say much about the new Terminate method, but I do have an app (NOTE: Not a game) that  does the following at certain points

```
private void Kill()
{
   new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game().Exit();
}
```

This app passed certification without any problems. This was an app for both WP7 and WP8 so I did not have the ability to use Terminate().