# How can I correctly close an application in Application_Launching event

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to close my app if network not available.

I check network in `App.cs`:

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                //close my app
            }
            else
            {
                 //continue to work
            }
        }
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that just closing your application is a good solution. You should at least notify the user first.

Comment: Of course, before closing, I will show a message that will explain to the user why the application will now close

Comment: This isn't a great idea in `Launching`. GetIsNetworkAvailable can take over 10s. In that case you'll be killed by the OS before you even start as you ran out of time to show your first page.

Comment: Wow! I did't know, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add reference to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game` i'm sure you can achieve exit with this code and it will be ok. if you wanna show message box you have to do it in main page

what i would do:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
               MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show(Sorry, no internet connection is available.do you want to exit the application , "Oops...", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
                if (m == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    var g = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game();
                        g.Exit();
                }
            }           
        }
```

you should provide a "gentle" way for closing

> **5.1.2 - App closure**
>
> ```
> The app must handle exceptions raised by the any of the managed or native System API 
> and not close unexpectedly. During the certification process, the app is monitored 
> for unexpected closure. An app that closes unexpectedly fails certification. The app
> must continue to run and remain responsive to user input after the exception is
> handled.
> ```

[for more information visit this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184840%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your response! It looks like this is what I need, but I can't add reference to Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game? How can I add reference in WP 8 project?

Comment: add reference > browse >`your directory in my case` Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Windows\x86

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 gives an error "In the project can not add a reference to a later version or incompatible link", but I think I can resolve this problem, thank!

Comment: This API isn't available on WP8. You'll have to use Application.Current.Terminate().

Comment: I found a way how to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881005/how-to-install-xna-game-studio-on-visual-studio-2012, but it's hard.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
Application.Current.Terminate();
```

Comment: Thanks you, I checked this method and it works, but I found post in SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460571/using-app-current-terminate-method-in-windows-phone-8 and in the post written that "ApplicationClosing even handler won't be raised after it", I think that's not really what I want, but in any case, thanks!